# How can I do multi class classification using naive bayes classifier?

Tags: data-structures

How can I do multi class classification using naive bayes classifier?

I am developing diseases classification system based on symptoms. I know training data is needed. But I don't have. I have only probabilities of symptoms for each disease. Is it possible to develop?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of extending simple classifiers to do multi class classification:

Source Wikipedia

The first one is called **One-vs.-rest** strategy. It involves training a single classifier per class, with the samples of that class as positive samples and all other samples as negatives. This strategy requires the base classifiers to produce a real-valued confidence score for its decision. During inference, you give a sample to each model, retrieve the probabilities of belonging to the positive class and chose the class where the classifier is most confident.

The second way is called **one-vs.-one (OvO)** reduction, one trains K (K − 1) / 2 binary classifiers for a K-way multiclass problem; each receives the samples of a pair of classes from the original training set, and must learn to distinguish these two classes. At prediction time, a voting scheme is applied: all K (K − 1) / 2 classifiers are applied to an unseen sample and the class that got the highest number of "+1" predictions gets predicted by the combined classifier. This approach can lead to ambiguity in some cases.

I would recommend using One vs Rest. It is already implemented in some packages such as Sklearn

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html